# How to take advantage of filters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I've read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-pipes-filters.htm) that

> To make a pipe, put a vertical bar (`|`) on the command line between two commands.

then

> When a program takes its input from another program, performs some operation on that input, and writes the result to the standard output, it is referred to as a filter.

So I've first tried the `ls` command whose output is:

```
Desktop    HelloWord.java    Templates            glassfish-4.0
Documents  Music             Videos               hs_err_pid26742.log
Downloads  NetBeansProjects  apache-tomcat-8.0.3  mozilla.pdf
HelloWord  Pictures          examples.desktop     netbeans-8.0
```

Then `ls | echo` which outputs absolutely nothing.

I'm looking for a way to take advantages of `pipelines` and `filters` in my bash script. Please help.

Comment: try something like `ls | less`

Comment: I nkow this works. But I'm try to understand why `the result of ls` is not passing as argument to `echo` as it's said

Comment: @SalathielGenèse, it didn't say that it passes things as *arguments*, it says that it passes things as *input*.

Comment: As a pointer for a future you, `ls | xargs echo` (which can be abbreviated to just `ls | xargs`) does more or less what it is you are attempting.  But you need to learn the basics properly before this will actually be useful.

Comment: `it didn't say that it passes things as arguments, it says that it passes things as input.` Thanks. --- `But you need to learn the basics properly before this will actually be useful` Thanks too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what others have said - if your command (`echo` in this example) does not read from standard input you can use `xargs` to "feed" this command from standard input, so

```
ls | echo
```

doesn't work, but

```
ls | xargs echo
```

works fine.

Comment: Thanks very much! I've read a lot about shell since, but i'll soon think about certification :) Many many thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

`echo` doesn't read from standard input. It only writes its command-line arguments to standard output. The `cat` command is what you want, which takes what it reads from standard input to standard output.

```
ls | cat
```

(Note that the pipeline above is a little pointless, but does demonstrate the idea of a pipe. The command on the right-hand side *must* read from standard input.)

Don't confuse command-line arguments with standard input.

Comment: Please I'm writing a script an I've its could be good for using filter. How to perfom it please.

Comment: Your question is far too general. Any command that reads from standard input and writes to standard output could be considered a filter of some type.

Comment: I have a script called `app.sh` and need to use it as `apt-get install --yes --print-uris vlc | grep \' | cut -d\' -f2 | app.sh`

Comment: Please post that as a separate question, as it is far different from the general question asked here.

Answer (score 2):

`echo` doesn't read standard input. To try something more useful, try

```
ls | sort -r
```

to get the output sorted in reverse, 
or

```
ls | grep '[0-9]'
```

to only keep the lines containing digits.